# Using amCharts with maven and spring in a J2EE project

Tags: java, maven, jsp, spring-mvc, amcharts

I want to use amCharts on my J2EE spring project, with Maven.

Searching on web, I've found that added this rows to pom.xml to download amcharts for maven:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>amcharts</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

But how can I use amChart in my JSP Page?

I don't understand how use the ".js" script in the page or which import I've to do in the JSP page.

I've checked under Maven Dependencies directory and found amcharts-3.20.13.jar but how use it on my pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Have you chekced this example](https://github.com/SteKoe/amcharts-java) I think for using the .js you need to download from the official page

[Official link](https://www.amcharts.com/)
and downloand the js add to your project and follow this tutorial for using JavaScript files in JSP [tutorial for using js in jsp](http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-javascript-in-jsp/29895)

Comment: Yes I've read that example. However, I've download .js file and add to my project directly (without maven). Thanks for your time!